# level crossing counting with python

Tags: python, count, statistics

Correct me or ask me for informations if it is unclear, I try to be precise as possible. I have pandas series / a list , with values with a range between 1 and 30. and a class list with the same steps. Now I want to do a cross level counting of the list for my classes. In the Picture below I described what I want to do. What is the best way to loop through my list and count the number of occurence in the classes ?

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def Rand(start, end, num):
res = []
for j in range(num):
    res.append(random.randint(start, end))

return res

s=Rand(-1,20,50)


#number of classes 
classlist=np.linspace(1,30,40)
for yc in classlist:
    plt.axhline(y=yc)
    plt.plot(s)
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your posted code merely plots the data set and evenly-space class lines; there's no attempt to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: @Prune I am aware of that what you are saying but my attempts where not working and since my for loops where rubbish I thought I could ask in that way.